# Transistors in power supply circuits

Tags: power-supply, transistors, voltage-regulator

In a circuit similar to this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv7Z7J.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What's the use of the transistors?

Comment: I want to say "they balance the circuit".

Comment: Please tell  us, what is the purpose of the circuit? What do you want to achieve? Do you have a source for the circuit? Because to me, it does not make sense.

Comment: Neither the transistors nor the entire circuit serve any useful purpose whatsoever.

Comment: They short circuit the bridge rectifier output, hopefully blowing a fuse somewhere before they start a fire.

Comment: As shown they are of no use and will in most cases be destroyed immediately. Where did the circuit come from? (web link)

Answer (score 5):

This is bonkers.
Actually... if the transformer is the right size compared to the transistors, chances are that the emitters will blow off cleanly and the B-C junction will either conduct as a forward diode, or fuse together to conduct entirely :-)

Are you sure this schematic is complete enough, around the transistors?

Transistor totems vaguely similar to this are typical for class AB analog power amplifiers in audio - except that center point where the emitters join is an output. And the bases need to be driven appropriately etc.

Comment: Well, if the transistors blow symmetrically in the right way, we get a perfectly serviceable +/- 1.25 V supply.

Answer (score 0):

Something is very wrong.

The BE paths of the transistor form an almost ideal short circuit and will be destroyed if the transformer supplies enough current.

Secondly the BC junctions start to work as diode if they survive the BE problem.

So there must be more to it. If the design is yours then take out the transistors and connect the LM inputs directly to the + and - of the rectifier.